# Line item custom field value not be saved after update line item

Tags: commerce, entities

I added a custom field into line item type, but it cannot be edit on order edit page. My environment: commerce_kickstart-7.x-2.22(With IEF 1.5 and the widget: Inline entity form - Multiple values)

Steps to produce this issue:

- Add a "field_additional_information" text field on    admin/commerce/config/line-items/product/fields, Do not include it on    "add to Cart from".
- Switch widget line item manager into inline entity form - multiple values.
- Edit order on admin/commerce/orders/%commerce_order/edit, click "Edit" link to edit a line item, "field_additional_information" field is shown, fill something in it.
- Reopen admin/commerce/orders/%commerce_order/edit page, click "Edit" link again, the value of "field_additional_information" field is not be shown(leave blank). Check database, the value is not be saved.

Many problems on Drupal Commerce make me distracted recently. Any comment or help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to "save" the whole form at bottom of the page, not only update that line.